# Events still attached after calling destroy() method on sagepayCheckout

Tags: javascript, opayo

I'm currently integrating SagePay via the dropin checkout. Our site is such that a user can select paying by sagepay in which case we instantiate the drop-in checkout but then could switch to another payment method requiring us to remove/destroy the checkout without refreshing the page. I have implemented this as per the documentation:

```html
sp = sagepayCheckout({
  merchantSessionKey: sagepaySessionKey
});
sp.form();    

// and

sp.destroy();
```

However. Once we try to submit the checkout form after calling the destroy method, something in the sagepay-dropin.js file is throwing an error (see below). The documentation suggests that destroy() "Removes the iFrame from the container and unregisters any events that may have been registered." But it seems that some events are still attached to the form submission.

Can you suggest a way of overcoming this so we can still submit our checkout form once a user has selected sagepay then switched to another payment method. Thanks.

```html
sagepay-dropin.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null
    at Object.a [as sendMessage] (sagepay-dropin.js:11)
    at v (sagepay-dropin.js:11)
    at T (sagepay-dropin.js:11)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (sagepay-dropin.js:11)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this in the end. There's no way to remove the event listeners that the dropin checkout binds to your form because they're added via an anonymous function. Instead, I had to bind an earlier event listener to the submit event which checks the payment method being used and if it's not sagepay it uses stopImmediatePropagation() to prevent the sagepay event from firing.

```html
paymentForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    if($("#paymenttype").val() != 9) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```